# Codeigniter login issue.

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I have codeigniter powered application and whenever i tried to log in on local server it doesn't let me in without any error message. But when I login in live server it works fine.

```
#What might be main causes of this issue.
#My config file and database settings are correct
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['phpass_hash_portable'] = TRUE;
//database settings:
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'alumniconnect';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

I am using **phpass** for hashing password and **tank_auth** for authentication.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error? check your .htaccess.

Comment: So, does it gives you an blank page or does it stops executing code?

Comment: I found that **tank auth** logs in user successfully but after redirect to the another page it destroys session again.